# Subtracting next date value from the current date

Tags: php

Thanks for the insight, although it didn't work for me. these  are my code:

```
<?php 

$_SESSION['start'] = $_GET['start'];
$_SESSION['end']=   $_GET['end']; 

?>

                                                            <?php 

$end=$_SESSION['end'];
$start=$_SESSION['start'];                                    $date_end=$end;
$date_start=$start;
$night=$date_end - $date_start;  

?>
```

So immediately the $date_end enter the next month, it will give me a error value.

Comment: Post your attempts too. What you have tried so far..

Comment: Show some code .Use date_diff() function it will help you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php use this link this will give you what you expected

Answer (score 3):

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

For php > 5.3 you can use [datetime.diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2015-04-24");
$date2 = new DateTime("2015-05-05");
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";

//difference 11 days
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and to everyone who contributed  to this.

Comment: i'm having trouble with this line $interval = $date1->diff($date2); This is the message it shows : Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index_date.php on line 4. Please help

Comment: "__For php > 5.3 you can use datetime.diff__"